# I want to be able to merge the content for every 25 rows into a single row in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

My Excel document has only 1 column and +1700 rows. I want to merge the data from every 25 rows into a single row. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How is the data to be merged?

Comment: I am hoping the formula can help with that too. :) I was using concatenate but not sure if that's the best one to use.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  Try posting the formula using concatenate and what exactly isn't working.

Comment: Do you want your data in 25 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a new sheet (or wherever you want your transposed data, as long as it does not overlap with the original data) select the top row (25 columns). Without changing the selection, type the following into the formula bar:

```
=TRANSPOSE(OFFSET($A$1:$A$25,25*(ROWS($1:1)-1),0))
```

where `A1:A25` are the first 25 items in your original list. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the formula as an array in the 25-cell range. You can then fill down all 25 columns at once until all your data is transposed.

If the formulas are troublesome, you can copy the entire transposed range and paste special the values only back into the same range.

**Example:**

[image]

**Explanation of formula:**

There are three key parts to this formula.

- `TRANSPOSE` does just what it says. It takes a column and changes it into a row, and vice versa. Since you want the formula to spit out 25 values, you must select 25 cells and enter the formula as one array formula.
- `ROWS` returns the number of rows in a range. The range specified in the formula `$1:1`, increments by one row as the formula is filled down. Hence, in the top row, the `ROWS(...)` function returns 1, in the second row -- 2, in the third row -- 3, etc.
- `OFFSET` does the work in the formula. It allows you to specify a starting range and how many rows you would like to offset it by. So, for each row, you would like the row offset to be incremented by 25. This can be achieved by multiplying the aforementioned `ROWS` function minus 1 by 25. The minus 1 is necessary to make the top row have no offset.

Comment: How do you merge the data for each row? Do you use concatenate on AC for for D to AB?

Comment: It wasn't clear to me from the question that the desire was to concatenate the data. I asked for clarification but did not get a response.

Comment: Thank you so much Excellll! This formula saved me SO much time!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of `=CONCATENATE()` and `=TRANSPOSE()` to combine 25 rows into a single cell.

[image]

Source: [Quickly combine text in multiple cells using this trick! [Formulas]](http://web.archive.org/save/chandoo.org/wp/2014/01/13/combine-text-values-quick-tip/)

Comment: +1 The `F9` thing is a nice trick. But there are minimum 3 steps which cannot be automated via autofill. This means 1700 rows / 25 rows * 3 manual edits = 204 manual edits. I think this is not the way to go

Comment: Personally, I'd save the Excel file as a text file, then use Notepad++ and run a macro that goes to the end of the line, presses delete to bring up previous line to the current line, Home, then down arrow. Repeat this 25 times. Then down arrow to create a new row set then repeat again.